# Route [designations.addmore] not defined

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5.4

I get an issue with the route as follows.

> Route [designations.addmore] not defined

I tried to define routes but still i get the same error.Here is my code

**View**

```
<a href="{{ route('designations.addmore',  $data->id) }}">Add more</a>
```

**Routes.php**

```
  Route::get('designations/addmore', ['as' => 'designations.addmore', 'uses' => 'Designations@addmore']);
```

**Controller**

```
 <?php

namespace TCG\Voyager\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use TCG\Voyager\Facades\Voyager;

class Designations extends Controller
{

    public function addmore()
    {
       echo 'hello';
    }


}
```

Please help me.

Comment: its an addmore  link.mean registers users extra details will add like this.so id should be passed@Niklesh

Answer (score 0):

Change your route like this

```
Route::get('designations/addmore', 'Designations@addmore')->name('designations.addmore');
```

and get route in anchor like this

```
<a href="{{ route('designations.addmore') }}">view</a>
```

remove second param from `route` because no param in your route.